# Opening files from Centos command line in Sublime Text on Windows

Tags: windows-10, sublimetext3, centos7

I am puttying into my Centos 7 terminal on Windows 10.  I would like to be able to open and edit the Linux files using sublime text rather than having to edit right in the terminal. Any thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: You can just create symlink for sublime and use within windows power shell i guess. Try finding symlink for sublime text 3 you will get many suggestions

Comment: You can use the [SFTP](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SFTP) package (it's commercial but you can try it for free) on your Windows machine to open and edit files on the Linux machine. Probably what you want in this case is [RemoteSubl](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/RemoteSubl) though.

Answer (score 1):

Get a copy of the Windows apps -- "WinSCP" (for SFTP and use as a remote filemanager, etc. and includes putty), and "Notepad Plus Plus" (Notepad++) ... easy way to edit files on remote server. All are free downloads.

Answer (score 0):

I personally like nano, its really easy to use

```
nano /path/to/file.c
```

ctrl + x to exit, ctrl+o to output the file with a y/n save prompt

If you want to use sublime, do the following

```
$> wget -qO - https://download.sublimetext.com/sublimehq-pub.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
$> echo "deb https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list
$> sudo apt-get update
$> sudo apt-get install sublime-text
```

Then this line will show you the sublime help options

```
$> subl -h
```

Assuming this:

```
$> subl /path/to/file.txt
```

Comment: Will this open up my sublime text editor in Windows 10 though? I'm working with linux on windows

Comment: Thanks for the nano suggestion Joe. That is a real help. Appears to be much better than vi

Comment: No problem, i love nano <3